# How Do I Pass an Object to a Function Within a Class Using a Caller Method in Python?

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter, parameter-passing

I'm recreating a program I've been working on that previously used variables for Tkinter settings. I didn't really use objects before and I'm trying to now. I have tried watching different videos and looking up guides without any luck. The goal is to make my program as modular as possible using separate .py files for calculations and GUI functions. I'm not sure if using objects is appropriate for what I'm doing.

I can't get the windowsSettings object to pass to the createWindow method. I get an error saying "**init**() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'width', 'height', 'title', and 'state'"

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
tkRoot = tk.Tk()
tkRoot.withdraw()


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, width, height, title, state):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.resolution = str(width) + 'x' + str(height)
        self.title = title
        self.state = state

    def createWindow(self):
        tkRoot.geometry(self.resolution)
        tkRoot.title(self.title)


windowSettings = MainWindow(800, 600, 'Program Name', 'zoomed')

caller = MainWindow(windowsSettings)
caller.createWindow(windowSettings)


tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: `caller = MainWindow(windowsSettings)` Check the variable name as the name is `windowSettings` but you use `windowsSettings` above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are new to OOPs

Fix your code to below.

```
windowSettings = MainWindow(800, 600, 'Program Name', 'zoomed')
windowSettings.createWindow()
```

Once created with windowSettings = MainWindow(..), windowSettings becomes an instance of MainWindow.

You can find tonnes of articles on OOPs online

Comment: Yeah while I've used Python for awhile I never delved into objects. How would I go about getting the self.resolution into the createWindow method?